# Как подружить ISKRA JS с программой на Python

Tags: python, pyqt5

Есть необходимость по нажатью кнопки в программе на Python включать лампочку на плате ISKRA JS
Это код для искры

```
var myLed = require('@amperka/led').connect(B3);
myLed.turnOn();
myLed.brightness(0.6);
myLed.turnOff();
```

Я не пойму, как их подружить, что и куда и как нужно отправлять из программы на питоне. Не пойму, что нужно загуглить. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться

Comment: Программа на python где запускается?

Comment: Предполагаю, что вы программой на Python со стационарного компьютера хотите управлять платой iskra js. Во-первых, нужно понимать, как у вас плата подсоединена к компу - по USB? Если да, то на плате нужно слушать serial порт, а программа на компе должна в serial данные передавать. Для искры см http://wiki.amperka.ru/js:serial, для Python см. модуль pyserial: https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial

Comment: Да, я понимаю, что нужно найти ком порт, думаю с этим бы проблем не возникло. А дальше что делать?

Comment: На питоне (pyqt5) я написал программку, по нажатию кнопки должен отправляться сигнал на плату. В вот что это за сигнал, как его отправлять, не могу понять что гуглить

Comment: Вот через serial посылаете сигнал в виде текста на плату, на плате получаете.

Comment: Понял, ладно! Буду разбираться

Comment: А как пометить ответ, как "лучший ответ"? :)

Comment: Никак, это не ответ, это комментарии.